# Must a server read the body of a PUT request, even when generating a '401 Not Authorized' response?

Tags: http

Is a HTTP server expected to read the whole request body from a PUT request, even if access is denied?

Or is it compliant to return a 401 Not Authorized, without reading anything or only a small part of the body. (And add 'Connection: close' to prevent the connection from being reused)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be careful: unless I'm missing something not reading the whole request body might block the client (trying to send it).

Note that this can be avoided by including

Expect: 100-continue

See [RFC 2616, Section 8.2.3](http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc2616.html#rfc.section.8.2.3)

Comment: Your answer matches my experiences with the Vista Miniredirector (which doesn't send an expect header as far as I can see).

Answer (score 2):

No, your webserver won't have to read the the whole body of the http request.

There is no necessity mentioned in the RFC

> 10.4.2 401 Unauthorized
>
> The request requires user
>   authentication. The response MUST
>   include a WWW-Authenticate header
>   field (section 14.47) containing a
>   challenge applicable to the requested
>   resource. The client MAY repeat the
>   request with a suitable Authorization
>   header field (section 14.8). If the
>   request already included Authorization
>   credentials, then the 401 response
>   indicates that authorization has been
>   refused for those credentials. If the
>   401 response contains the same
>   challenge as the prior response, and
>   the user agent has already attempted
>   authentication at least once, then the
>   user SHOULD be presented the entity
>   that was given in the response, since
>   that entity might include relevant
>   diagnostic information. HTTP access
>   authentication is explained in "HTTP
>   Authentication: Basic and Digest
>   Access Authentication" [43].

Source: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

Comment: Technically correct, but some clients (e.g. WinINET) don't do parallel sends and receives, and thus will send the entire body before listening for a response.